# Cypress while running the file

Tags: cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am facing issue in cypress while running one of the file
the issue is it seems in node module
giving the Screenshort
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SObM.png)

Please provoide me the some stpes so that i will go ahead

I have tried to  npm install again and run

Comment: while running the script npx cypess open then only it is coming

Comment: "We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed."

Comment: Could you provide the .feature file line which throws an error?

Comment: We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.